# Question about unhandled promise rejection in async function Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, try-catch

I need to return something inside the catch block instead of throwing an error. Inside the catch block I'm executing retryGenerateThing function recursively and if the retry is greater than or equal to 3 return with status code 503. It looks like I'm not using catch block and just returning inside if else statement which is causing an issue but not sure how to resolve this issue. Below is the error I'm getting.

*(node:8852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)*

```
    try {
        await generateThing(ID)
    } catch (err) {
      const retryGenerateThing = async () => {
            
            const result = await getRetryCount(ID)
            retryCnt = result[0].RETRY_CNT

            if(retryCnt < 3) {
                try {
                    await generateThingRetry(ID)
                } catch (err) {
                    retryGenerateFactors()
                }
            } else {
                return res.status(503).send('FAILED - generateThing')   
            }
        }

        retryGenerateThing()
}
```